# How to organize third-party java_library rules?

Tags: bazel

I have many `BUILD` files that require Jetty or other common Java libraries (SLF4J, Lucene, Guava, etc.). Each of these has a set of other JARs that it references. I would like to know the best practice for organizing these declarations and their dependencies in a large project.

For example, using `generate_workspace` via `bazel run //src/tools/generate_workspace -- --artifact=org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.8.v20160314` I get the following `BUILD`

```
# The following dependencies were calculated from:
# org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.8.v20160314


java_library(
    name = "org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_http",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    exports = [
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_http//jar",
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_util//jar",
    ],
)

java_library(
    name = "org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_util",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    exports = [
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_util//jar",
    ],
)

java_library(
    name = "javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    exports = [
        "@javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api//jar",
    ],
)

java_library(
    name = "org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_server",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    exports = [
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_server//jar",
        "@javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api//jar",
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_http//jar",
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_io//jar",
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_util//jar",
    ],
)

java_library(
    name = "org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_io",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    exports = [
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_io//jar",
        "@org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_util//jar",
    ],
)
```

and `WORKSPACE`

```
# The following dependencies were calculated from:
# org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.8.v20160314


# org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.8.v20160314
maven_jar(
    name = "org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_http",
    artifact = "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:9.3.8.v20160314",
)

# org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.8.v20160314
# org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.8.v20160314
maven_jar(
    name = "org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_util",
    artifact = "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:9.3.8.v20160314",
)

# org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.8.v20160314
maven_jar(
    name = "javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api",
    artifact = "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0",
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_server",
    artifact = "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.3.8.v20160314",
)

# org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.8.v20160314
maven_jar(
    name = "org_eclipse_jetty_jetty_io",
    artifact = "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:9.3.8.v20160314",
)
```

files.

I have a dependency on jetty-server and jetty-util in many projects. Is there a better practice than repeating this information in each `BUILD` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you'd put the `generate_workspace`-generated BUILD file in the root of your workspace (next to your WORKSPACE file) and then, in other BUILD files, you'd reference whatever target they needed to depend on. For example, in src/main/java/com/your-project/subcomponent/BUILD, you might say:

```
java_library(
    name = "my-servlet",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    deps = [
        "//:javax_servlet_javax_servlet_api",
        # other deps...
    ],
)
```